# EntityFramework Core 5 does not connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, ubuntu, sql-server-2008, .net-core, entity-framework-5

I installed dotnet core 5 on ubuntu 21.04. I created a webapi project with VS Code and managed to run everything smoothly.

I installed EF5 to the project and am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008

**DbContext**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Models
{
    public partial class Banco : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
        public Banco() : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=<<servidor>>; Database=<<banco>>; User Id=<<user>>; Password=<<senha>>;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Cliente>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.codcli });

        }

    }

}
```

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Models
{
    public partial class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int codcli { get; set; }

        public string nomcli { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace dotnetc_webapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("")]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic Get()
        {
            Models.Banco banco = new Models.Banco();
            var cliente = banco.Cliente.Take(10).Select(cli => cli).ToArray();
            return new OkObjectResult(cliente);

        }
    }
}
```

When running the project with the command **dotnet watch run** it opens the browser and when trying to connect to the bank, it shows the following error:

```
SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

on the line: `var cliente = banco.Cliente.Take(10).Select(cli => cli).ToArray();`

What I find strange is that if I take the same project without any code changes and run within Windows 10 it can connect to the database and receive data from clients normally and not in ubuntu.

I've tried these procedures

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

I don't know if this is the right way or I'm missing something.

I'm dependent on windows just because of this project, I have to use a VM to run windows because of it. I would love to solve this problem and just be using linux.

Comment: Note: SQL Server 2008 was end-of-life a few years ago - it may be hard to get much support for things like weak TLS demands, etc

Comment: But if I run the same source code in VSCode in Windows 10, I can access the database and receive data normally, but in linux it presents this problem.

Comment: yes, I understood; the point I'm making is: I doubt anyone at Microsoft is validating this setup or interested in fixing it, since it is an officially obsolete product version

Comment: Actually I have SQL Server 2012 and I get the same error. I am looking for an answer myself